# ffmpeg: change alpha channel of a showwaves filter

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, alpha-channel

I've been trying to figure this issue out for a few hours and I can't seem to find any solution.

I'm creating a video from an .mp3 and some images with the following command

```
fmpeg.exe -y -i temp\audio.mp3 -loop 1 -i Bokeh\frame-%03d.png -r 25 -filter_complex "[0:a] showwaves=size=1280x100:mode=line:r=25[wave];[1:v][wave] overlay=y=H-h:eval=init[canvas];[canvas]drawtext=fontfile='./tools/impact.ttf':fontsize=42:text='ORGANIKISMNESS':x=20:y=(h-170-text_h*2.20):fontcolor=white:shadowy=2:shadowx=2:shadowcolor=black,drawtext=fontfile='./tools/impact.ttf':fontsize=42:text='RETURN TO THE SOURCE PT.2 (ORGANIKISMNESS REMIX)':x=20:y=(h-170-text_h):fontcolor=white:shadowy=2:shadowx=2:shadowcolor=black" -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -tune stillimage -crf 19 -movflags faststart "videos\Organikismness-Return to the Source Pt.2 (Organikismness Remix).mp4"
```

I'm trying to make the [wave] (showwaves) filter have some sort of alpha channel, to be slightly transparent to be overlayed on the rest of the video later.

So far I've tried the `blend` filter, but this complains that the sources are not the same size (one is 1280x720, the showwaves source is 1280x100).

I tried the `colorchannelmixer` filter, but I couldn't figure out how this should work.

Anyone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: What is your result? Is it overlaid on opaque BG? Also provide the consol output of the command.

Comment: The result is something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZexJQRLKx8

I would really like to have the black background on the bottom strip transparent.

edit: actually the output of that command is - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H82GtJFReg4

Comment: colorchannelmixer=1:0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:0:1:0:0.3:0.3:0.3:0,format=rgba

Answer (score 4):

FFmpeg **[colorkey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey)** filter

```
//colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0.5
[0:a] showwaves=size=1280x100:mode=line:r=25, colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0.5[wave]
```

`0x000000` is 0xRRGGBB color *?*
`0.1` is **Similarity** percentage
`0.5` is **Blending** percentage

[image: ffmpeg wave trasparency]

Comment: You two guys saved my night :)