# Set background color /transparency for ffmpeg showwaves filter

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors

The posts [here](https://superuser.com/a/843834/328722) were super helpful.

I am just using the [showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves) filter (at the moment) to generate a visualization, like this:

[image: show waves visualization]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=1280x480:colors=Magenta|Azure|White[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-b:a 360k -r:a 44100  output.mkv
```

I tried overlaying this video over another one (using [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org), in case the background only *appeared* to be "black", but it was still there.

The Showwaves filter itself doesn't have an option for background color.

Based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/717222/ffmpeg-change-alpha-channel-of-a-showwaves-filter), it looks like the [colorkey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorkey) filter can at least make the black transparent, but the following code is still resulting in a sold black background:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=1280x480:colors=Magenta|Azure|White:r=25, colorkey=0x000000:0.1:0.1[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-b:a 360k -r:a 44100  output.mkv
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[showwaves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showwaves) outputs a transparent background (unless your `ffmpeg` is super old), so you can [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) it onto the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=1280x480:colors=Magenta|Azure|White[sw]; \
 color=s=1280x480:c=#00ff00[bg]; \
 [bg][sw]overlay=format=auto:shortest=1,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Audio is [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c:a copy`) instead of re-encoded.

Comment: Thanks for also suggesting stream copying.